# Sending an email via batch file

Tags: php, html, email, batch-file, ip

Okay so my ultimate goal is to have an autorun file that I can place in an external drive or on a flash disk or even a cd that if run will execute a bunch of crap that eventually sends the computers ip info back to me. Thus far this is what I have...

A batch file that

- opens a cmd window and runs ipconfig /all > tcpinfo.txt to store all the ipconfig in a file
- Then the file creates an html file

  echo ^http://anthonyrussell.info/scripts/sendmail.php? 
            computerinfo="this is where the ipconfig info should go"^>^^^ >>sendEmail.html`

--The last thing the batch file does is executes the html file

The HTML file redirects to a php page that I created that shoots an email out with the GET information passed by the html file we created.

So it all works EXCEPT I cant get the ipconfig info into the html code....

Any ideas?

below is the bat code that I am using. Feel free to run it. I have it configured to where if you add in your email where it says altEmail= it will send it to where ever you want for testing. Otherwise it gets routed to me.

save this as whatevernameyouwant.bat

```
cd desktop
ipconfig /all > tcpinfo.txt
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"content="0;url=http://anthonyrussell.info/scripts/sendmail.php?computerinfo=ip:127.0.0.1&altEmail="^>^</head^>^</html^> >> sendEmail.html
sendEmail.html
```

### UPDATE

So sometimes the simplest answer is truely the best. The whole point of this scenario was to capture computer information from someone that may or may not have stolen a drive or disk.

The idea was to have it 
autorun->launch batch file -> capture comp info ->create html file -> phone home with info

What I ended up doing was instead of capturing the public IP from the command prompt (which I am now convinced can't be done) I simply just create an html file, launch it, and on my server capture the visitor ID then email it in the body along with the computers name that I capture in the command prompt.

Thanks for everyones input. This was a fun exercise

Comment: i dont know why stack overflow is adding in so many ^ symbols but where ever you see them there should only be one

Comment: Can I ask why you create this?! do you want to create a trojan?

Comment: Outside of curiosity? I want to create an auto run file to place on my externals that if they are ever stolen I am emailed the ip address.

Comment: Then you can encrypt it!!! for Windows use Bitlocker or Free [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq)

Comment: They are encrypted but that doesn't tell me where they are

Comment: An IP address also doesn't tell where it is... also, what if someone stole it and has no internet connection? or a good AV software that blocks autorun.inf.... just use TrueCrypt.

Comment: @AMR: What if the burglar is running Linux :) :) :) or Mac OS

Comment: We can what if it all day lol... An IP gives a good approximation of where the drive would be along with the MAC ID address and I can also add in a whoAMI to see if someone named their computer after themselves. The whole point of this though is just an exercise to see if I CAN do it.

Comment: @FilipeYaBaPolido touche' again lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the IP address from `ipconfig` into a for statement to get the variable like this:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4"') do set ipaddress=%%a
```

then change your echo to

```
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<meta HTTP EQUIV="REFRESH"content="0;url=http://anthonyrussell.info/scripts/sendmail.php computerinfo=ip:%ipaddress%&altEmail="^>^</head^>^</html^> >> sendEmail.html
```

That being said, this will likely be a local IP address, not public, therefor useless. If I remember correctly there is no native way to get the public IP address.

**Edit:**

You could use a mix of VBS and batch

*getip.vbs*

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://ifconfig.me/ip", False
o.send
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell" ).Run "getip.bat" & o.responseText,0
```

*getip.bat*

```
cd desktop
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"content="0;url=http://anthonyrussell.info/scripts/sendmail.php?computerinfo=ip:%1&altEmail="^>^</head^>^</html^> >> sendEmail.html
sendEmail.html
```

This is just a slightly modified version of the solution provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/404926/how-to-get-my-external-ip-address-over-nat-from-the-windows-command-line).  Do note this is untested.

Comment: Hmmm it appears you are correct about not being able to get your public ip.... Well thank you for sucking all the fun out of this exercise! haha... At very least it is cool to know you can pull data from someones machine and with a mixture of bat html and php files recover it.

Comment: Added a solution for public ip.  Hopefully I added the fun back for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use CURL.
You can do GET,POST, and so many other usefull stuff.

Comment: It needs to be able to compile and run on any windows machine without any third party software. I am not familiar with CURL can it do that?

Comment: Batch files don't compile ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can put the output of ipconfig (or any other command) into a variable using backticks:

```
<?php
$ipconfig=`ipconfig`;
print $ipconfig;
```

You can either then use the php mail to mail the output (make sure you set the smtp server to a valid on in php config first or use a php smtp library like pear mail)

Comment: The php file isn't stored on a local system and the intention of the file is to be able to run from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the answer is the following.

I havent been able to get it to send the computer output properly yet but this is how you get the two together. The trick is to use the COPY command. So create half of the html file. Append in the computer information then append in the rest of the HTML file. Now to just make it work...

```
echo computerinfoblah >> computerInfoFile.txt
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"content="0;url=http://anthonyrussell.info/scripts/sendmail.php?computerinfo=" >> sendemail.html
COPY sendemail.html + computerInfoFile.txt
echo &altEmail="^>^</head^>^</html^> >> sendemail.html
sendemail.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to first address where you would be saving the txt file... If it was on a drive let's say E:\ then save it.

```
cd E:\
```

Then, I would save the data into a text file.

```
ipconfig /all > tcpinfo.txt
```

After that I would call it back declaring each line a variable such as this (Let's say I wanted the host line which in my case is line 4 in my text file)

```
< tcpinfo.txt (
set /p notimportant=
set /p notimportant=
set /p notimportant=
set /p hostname=
)
```

Then, if you wanted to send the data to your website and your page handles it correctly then you could just send the user directly to the website with the information such as:

```
start http://anthonyrussell.info/scripts/sendmail.php?hostname=%hostname%
```

You would have to specify what the GET'S then depending on what fields what you want. Then you take that data from the webpage and use it to send you the data to your email.

Answer (score 0):

If your client can connect to an smtp server then do that rather than using your web server. If powershell is installed there are built in cmdlets for sending emais. Just get your batch script to run powershell.exe and give it a script block to execute.